# How to change a digit in string to integer rather than its ASCII code?

Tags: c++, turbo-c++

Question : Write a program in a C++ to display the sum of digits present in a text file.

-->

```
#include<iostream.h>  
#include<fstream.h>  
int main()  
{  
 ifstream f1("Fees.txt");  
 int sum=0;  
 char n;  
 while(f1.eof()==0)  
 {  
  f1>>n;  
  if(isdigit(n))  
   {  
   sum=sum+n;  
   }  
 }  
    cout<<sum;  
}
```

I know the program's not working because string is changed to digit,( 1 changes to its ASCII code 49 instead of 1)
Please guide me
And is there a better way to approach the question?

**UPDATE** Ok so I changed the line sum+=n to sum+=n-'0'.
Still the program only seems to be working when there is a special character in addition to numbers in the text file Fees.txt.
  Example:

```
1 2 9
```

This does not work

```
1 2 9ok
```

This does work, any idea what's going on here?

Comment: you're almost there - just substract ASCII '0' from n

Comment: If you know the file is ASCII, then you can subtract the ASCII code of 0, i.e. `'0'`, to the char to get the proper digit. This is because the ASCII codes of 0,1,2,3... are consecutive, so adding 4 to the ASCII code of 0 you get the code for 4.

Comment: 1. It's not c++. 2. You should [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @luk32 This is C++.  It is old C++(most likely they are using TurboC++) but it is C++.  There is no `iostream` or `ifstream` in C

Comment: Somebody seems to be teaching you 1990s C++.

Comment: @NathanOliver: I think we can agree that pre-standard C++ is no longer "C++" in the general sense, without further qualification. It's been almost twenty years.

Comment: @NathanOliver Oh yea. My bad. `fstream` is certainly not c. But is `ifstream.h` c++?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Do we have a tag we can use to mark this as pre-standard C++?

Comment: @luk32 It is from before C++ was standardized.  Compilers like Turbo C++ use `<standard_header_name.h>` instead of `<standard_header_name>`.  I believe they cannot compile `<standard_header_name>`.

Comment: @NathanOliver: If only! I think a fair compromise for the time being is for OPs to tag [tag:turbo-c++] if they're using it. That almost always signifies the same thing (as you pointed out before), and seems reasonable given that by definition we'll need to know what non-standard dialect of primordial C++ is in use. We'd have to create the tag, though (or perhaps there's a would-be synonym already that I haven't found yet). We already use [tag:c++03], [tag:c++11] and [tag:c++14], after all.

Comment: @NathanOliver Ok, fair enough. I don't think you can call something c++ if it doesn't conform to any of the standard. At least here people tend to be very strict. But I don't mean to go into discussion as it's a rather POV based. I was honestly asking out of curiosity because I didn't recall standard libraries to have `.h` suffix, even in pre c++11, which would be c++99 I guess. Thanks for sharing the historical context.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well we do have [tag:turboc++].  Most likely it will need to be compiler specific since there was different flavors of pre-standard C++.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Yep, as I said. :) Good to know the tag does exist. Perhaps we can make the version with a hyphen into a synonym for clarity.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yeah my bad, I actually use <iostream> but teachers don't accept that, is there any other thing that points out I'm outdated? :P

Comment: @luk32 please see the update

Comment: @user3500780: It's a shame your teachers are training you to use obsolete technology that won't be of use in the job market :(

Comment: `while(f1.eof()==0)` is not right btw - you're checking too early and, although not invalid, the comparison to literal `0` is just weird

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit pls suggest what is new technology which I should be learning?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit isn't THIS c++?

Comment: @user3500780: Nope!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit  thenewboston and many teachers call THIS c++ tho?

Comment: @user3500780: Yes, sadly, many people do and say wrong things.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit do u have a link or any book that teaches thereal deal?

Comment: @user3500780 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score 3):

As you point out, the ASCII codes for digits do not start at zero, which is your problem. Luckily though, they do lie in a continuous range, so all you need to do is change the line:

```
sum=sum+n;
```

to

```
sum += (n - '0');
```

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with ASCII. The C and C++ standards require that the values of `'0'..'9'` be contiguous and increasing, so converting a character that represents a digit simply requires subtracting `'0'`, **regardless of the character encoding**. So:

```
sum += n - '0';
```

will fix the problem.